# a href anchor click, causes to lose focus on input element using jquery, firefox, IE 10

Tags: jquery, anchor

My problem occurs in IE10 and Firefox, but works in Chrome.

I have an anchor like this:

```
<a id="link-to-form" href="#bonus-form">
```

An also I have an input element that I have it focused using jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required />
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
   $('#firstname').focus();     
});
```

My problem is that when I press the anchor link, and it moves inside the page, the focus is lost from my input tag. I would like to keep the focus on my input, after I press the anchor link.

I have tried many things, last one was the following. But still it doesn't focus. Actually the click event is fired on the debugger, but immediately the anchor executes and it loses focus again:

```
$("#link-to-form").on("click", function (e) {
    $('#firstname').focus();
    return true;            
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick might be to store the currently focused element,
add a `regainLastFocus` class to any desired anchor 
and on click on that class elements: reset the focus to the stored jQuery element that was last focused

Don't forget to catch the `event` on click and use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

```
$("#link-to-form").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#firstname').focus();         
});
```

Comment: adding event.preventDefault(); simply stops the anchor. So it does remain focused, but the anchor is not followed.

Comment: @Aris are you sure? here is a demo try in FF: http://jsbin.com/ofiquj/1/edit As you can see the anchor is followed and the element gains focus.

Comment: @Roco, your fiddle works fine. Let me check again what's wrong and update you!

Comment: maybe it matters where I add my jquery code?  I have it at the end of the file, outside the $(document).ready(function(){. How to add a regainLastFocus? maybe this will help.